# Where is the Socket.IO client-side .js file located?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to get socket.io (Node library) to work.

I have the server-side js working, and it is listening. The socket.io website states simply:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

This is nice, however, what JS file am I importing!?!

I went into the node_modules directory, where I installed socket.io through npm, and inside `socket.io/lib/` is  `socket.io.js` file. However, this is server-side (uses the phrase `require()`, which errors on the client).

I have spent an hour looking around and I can't get any client .js file to work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I managed to eventually answer this for myself.

The socket.io getting started page isn't clear on this, but I found that the server side of socket.io automatically hosts the .js file on starting node, in the directory specified in the documentation:

```
"/socket.io/socket.io.js"
```

So you literally just point to this url regardless of your web app structure, and it works.

Comment: It's a file generated on the fly by the node server, yes. I also found odd how they don't say a word about this, it's almost as if they expect everyone to blindly copy their example without questioning what's going on in there.

Comment: And then when it doesn't work what do we do?  Here I am, searching S/O for answers... (and still not finding any).  I hate magic.

Comment: This only works if the process that is running socket-io server side is the same process that handled the route/served up the HTML/JS. -- otherwise you have to specify the URL:port such as `http://localhost:3466/socket.io/socket.io.js`. I.e. (obv) if you have one web app trying to reference a different process you need to specify the whole URL

Comment: @jleach try [one of these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56075477/476716)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest checking if your node_modules directory is at the top level of your app directory. Also, I do believe you need to specify a port number; you should write something like `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');`, where the port number is `1337`.

Comment: It could be worth mentioning that you can forgo the call to 'code'connect'code' and the URL all together if you intend to use your socket with the same protocol and on the same host and port by using       `var socket = io();` 
This will create your handle for future use and attempt to connect.

Answer (score 3):

If you did `npm install` then the client socket.io file is located at node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js

Source: [Socket get-started page](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/)

Comment: This is why stackoverflow is unfair. They blocked me from asking question. This is useful answer and it was -1. I gave you a vote so it is 0 now.

Answer (score 2):

The client is available in a few ways:

- supplied by the socket.io server at `/socket.io/socket.io.js`
- included via webpack as the module `socket.io-client`
- via the official CDN `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/<version>/socket.io.js`

For the first one, the server can be configured in a couple of ways:

```
// standalone
var io = require('socket.io')(port);

// with existing server from e.g. http.createServer or app.listen
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```