# node.js : failed to require socket.io from root

Tags: socket.io

my english is not good, sorry.

i have a clientfile chat.html. the code is started with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html> 
<head> 

<script src="socket.io-client.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
//mit dem Chatserver verbinden:
var socket = io.connect("http://test01.my-wan.de:8080");
```

at the console of the browser i received "failed to require socket.io from root".
The file socket.io-client.js is at the same directory of the file chat.html.
i have read a lot of posts about this problem, but i can't solve the problem.
Can anyone help me??? THANKS!

Comment: Did you followed the instructions from [the socket.io website](http://socket.io/#how-to-use)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you get the client file?

I asked a similar question a bit ago, as Socket.IO is vague on this point. This question seems a duplicate of my post here:

[Where is the Socket.IO client-side .js file located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757728/getting-the-right-client-side-socket-io-js-file)

The answer to the question is that Socket.IO, server side, automatically places the client side file, so you don't have to manually place it. The instructions on this are on the first page of their website.

Comment: Thank you!! I'm happy, it works. I will later post here the code.

Comment: Great! Was it my suggestion that fixed it? If so, if you don't mind, please remember to mark the answer as accepted.