# Socket.io: io.connect doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I use node.js with express.js framework. I Tried connect to server using io.connect on client side.

Template:

```
html
head
    title Example chat
    script(src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js")
    script(src="http://cdn.socket.io/stable/socket.io.js")
    script(src="javascripts/chat.js")
body
    form
        input(type="text" name="msg")
        input(type="submit")
```

It's chat.js:

```
var socket = io.connect('//localhost:8080');
```

app.js socket.io require:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);
```

Firebug gives an error:

TypeError: io.connect is not a function

What is it? How to fix it?

Thanks you.

Comment: Are you sure your server is listening on port 3000? 
Try also: 

`socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/');`

Comment: @Morrisda, TypeError: io.connect is not a function.

Tried to change port - same result.

Comment: that error is about - not receiving the socket.IO file from server. Check url once again, show some more code from server.

Comment: did you handle `app->get('/')` on server ?

Comment: Sorry, I use it for the first time.

Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/4Y5xAuW5 (It's app.js)

Comment: In your server app you should 

`var socketio = require('socket.io').listen(server);
socketio.on('connection', function(socket) {
console.log(socket);
});`

This will show on your terminal (where you run 'node server.js') if there's an actual incoming connection from client.

Answer (score 0):

Server-side

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io');
var app = express()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = io.listen(server);

server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("✔ Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.get('port'), app.settings.env);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

---

Client-side

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Then if you're wondering where that `socket.io.js` is found, it's [automatically generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757728/where-is-the-socket-io-client-side-js-file-located).