# socket.io/socket.io.js - not found. Node.js, express.js and socket.io app

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

Im getting error that socket.io/socket.io.js cannot be loaded. I've made this:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes');

var io = require('socket.io').listen(express);

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes

app.get('/', routes.index);

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

My layout.jade file looks like this:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    script(src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js')
    script(src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
    script.
      var socket = io();
  body!= body
```

and package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "2.5.8",
    "jade": ">= 0.0.1",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.2"
  }
}
```

I installed socket.io with npm, all files are in node_modules catalog. I've tried to copy socket.io.js file into /public but there's an error too. I tried to solve that problem in many ways - with socket.io docs, chat tutorial and StackOverflow post. Every time when i try to you socket.io problem occurs. Is anything wrong in my code? What should i do to make this thing work correctly?

Comment: In `.listen(express)` the `express` isn't a server.

Comment: thanks a lot. I change the .listen(express) to .listen(app) and now it works fine!

Comment: I am very sorry, i didn't looked into your comment, so answered at the bottom. @AlanSobieraj

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the Socket.IO client-side .js file located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757728/where-is-the-socket-io-client-side-js-file-located)

Answer (score 0):

Does running `npm update` in terminal fix this? (You might need to run it with elevated privileges with sudo or equivalent)

When you run an application with Node.js, it doesn't automatically install the dependencies. You'll need to use NPM (Node package manager). Their is an update command. In the directory with your `package.json` file, run this:

```
npm update
```

You might need elevated privileges. This is what it looks like on Mac OS X/Linux:

```
sudo npm update
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very much there, let me change few things in your **app.js**.
Try it now.

```
    var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes

app.get('/', routes.index);

var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

io.on("connection",function(socket){
    console.log("Application connected");

    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        console.log("Application Disconnected");
    });

    socket.on('ABC Event',function(value){
        console.log("ABC event catched from client value passed is :"+value);
        //do something
        io.emit('new event',passSomeJSONtoClient);
    });

});
```