# socket.io.js path in nodejs with localhost in windows

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have installed **node.js v0.10.31** and **npm v1.4.3** and also installed **node-uuid**, **socket.io** and **express**

I am trying to create a simple chat app, but the socket.io path i referred was so confusing. my installed socket.io path is **D:\program files\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io**  my project files in the localhost in **xampp** (for php)

referred from tutorials link **/socket.io/socket.io.js**  but my link in 
**D:\program files\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\socket.io.js**

how can i use to include `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` to ??

i have two files in my projectand i copied node_modules folder to project folder from nodejs

***app.js***

```
var constants = { court: { width: 600, height: 600 }, 
                  paddle: { width: 50, height: 15, delta: 3 },
                  ball: { radius: 10, deltaLeft: 3, deltaTop: 2, interval: 30 }
                };                         

var state = { paddles: {},
              ball: { left: 0, top: 0 },
              bottomPaddle: 0,
              topPaddle: 0,
              leftPaddle: 0,
              rightPaddle: 0
            };

var serverState = { intervalId: 0, 
                    connections: 0
                  };

var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    fs = require('fs');

app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
        function readfile_callback(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.writeHead(500);
                return res.end('Error loading index.html');
            }
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end(data);
        }
    );
};

function calculateBallPosition() {
    var left = state.ball.left + constants.ball.deltaLeft;
    var top = state.ball.top + constants.ball.deltaTop;

    if (left >= constants.court.width) {
        left = constants.court.width;
        constants.ball.deltaLeft = -constants.ball.deltaLeft;
    } else if (left <= 0) {
        left = 0;
        constants.ball.deltaLeft = -constants.ball.deltaLeft;
    }
    if (top + constants.ball.radius >= constants.court.height - constants.paddle.height) {
        if (state.bottomPaddle && 
            left > ( (state.paddles[state.bottomPaddle]/100) * constants.court.width - constants.paddle.width / 2) &&
            (left < ( (state.paddles[state.bottomPaddle]/100) * constants.court.width + constants.paddle.width / 2) ) ) {
            top = constants.court.height - constants.paddle.height - constants.ball.radius;
            constants.ball.deltaTop = -constants.ball.deltaTop;
        } else {
            //TODO: #1
            left = constants.court.width / 2;
            top = constants.court.height / 2;       
        }
    } else if (top <= 0) {
        top = 0;
        constants.ball.deltaTop = -constants.ball.deltaTop;
    }
    state.ball.left = left;
    state.ball.top = top;
};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    var paddleAdded = false;
    if (!state.bottomPaddle) {
        state.bottomPaddle = socket.id;
    } else if (!state.topPaddle) {
        state.topPaddle = socket.id;
    } else if (!state.leftPaddle) {
        state.leftPaddle = socket.id;
    } else if (!state.rightPaddle) {
        state.rightPaddle = socket.id;
    } else {
      // placeholder for fifth player
      return;
    }

    state.paddles[socket.id] = 50;

    socket.emit('environment', { court:  {  width:  constants.court.width, 
                                            height: constants.court.height,
                                         }, 
                                 paddle: {  width: constants.paddle.width, 
                                            height: constants.paddle.height,
                                            delta: constants.paddle.delta
                                         },
                                 ball: { radius: constants.ball.radius },
                                 player: { id: socket.id }
    });

    if ( !serverState.intervalId ) {
        serverState.intervalId = setInterval( function(){
            calculateBallPosition();
        }, constants.ball.interval );  
    }

    socket.intervalId = setInterval( function(){
        socket.emit('ball', { position: { left: state.ball.left, top: state.ball.top } }); 
        socket.emit('paddles', { positions: state.paddles, sides: {bottom: state.bottomPaddle, top: state.topPaddle, left: state.leftPaddle, right: state.rightPaddle }});
    }, constants.ball.interval );  

    socket.on('paddle', function (data) {
        state.paddles[socket.id] = data.left;
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        serverState.connections--;
        clearInterval( socket.intervalId );
        delete state.paddles[socket.id];

        if (state.bottomPaddle == socket.id)
            state.bottomPaddle = 0;
        else if (state.topPaddle == socket.id)
            state.topPaddle = 0;
        else if (state.leftPaddle == socket.id)
            state.leftPaddle = 0;
        else if (state.rightPaddle == socket.id)
            state.rightPaddle = 0;
        if ( serverState.connections == 0 ) {
            clearInterval( serverState.intervalId );
            serverState.intervalId = 0;
        }
        console.log('player left');
    });  

    console.log(serverState.connections);
    serverState.connections++;
});
```

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
      .topPlayer {
        -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
      }
      .leftPlayer {
        -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
      }
      .rightPlayer {
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="court"></canvas>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>

  var constants = { court: { width: 0, height: 0, adjusted: false }, 
                    colors: { court: "brown", ball: "black", paddle: "orange" },
                    paddle: { width: 0, height: 0, delta: 0 },
                    ball: { radius: 0 },
                    player: { id: 0 }
                  };                               

  var state = { paddles: {},
                ball: { left: 0, top: 0 },
                sides: {}
              };

  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost/pingv1'),
      canvas = document.getElementById("court"),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  socket.on('environment', function(data) {
    constants.court.width = data.court.width;
    constants.court.height = data.court.height;
    constants.paddle.delta = data.paddle.delta;
    constants.paddle.width  = data.paddle.width;
    constants.paddle.height  = data.paddle.height;
    constants.ball.radius = data.ball.radius;   
    constants.player.id = data.player.id;    
  });

  socket.on('paddles', function(data) {
    var paddles = data.positions;
    // Overwrite the server's version of my own paddle position
    // if I already know where I am so I don't redraw in the old spot.
    if (state.paddles[constants.player.id])
      paddles[constants.player.id] = state.paddles[constants.player.id];
    state.paddles = paddles;
    state.sides = data.sides;
    if (!constants.court.adjusted) {
        constants.court.adjusted = true;
        if (state.sides.top == constants.player.id)
            canvas.className = 'topPlayer';
        else if (state.sides.left == constants.player.id)
            canvas.className = 'leftPlayer';
        else if (state.sides.right == constants.player.id)
            canvas.className = 'rightPlayer';
    }
  });

  socket.on('ball', function (data) {
    state.ball.left = data.position.left;
    state.ball.top = data.position.top;
    drawCanvas();     
  });

  var drawCanvas = function() {
    canvas.width = constants.court.width;
    canvas.height = constants.court.height;
    ctx.fillStyle = constants.colors.court;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, constants.court.width, constants.court.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = constants.colors.paddle;
    ctx.fillRect((state.paddles[state.sides.bottom] / 100 * constants.court.width) - (constants.paddle.width / 2),
                 constants.court.height - constants.paddle.height, constants.paddle.width, constants.paddle.height);
    ctx.fillRect((state.paddles[state.sides.top] / 100 * constants.court.width) - (constants.paddle.width / 2),
                 0, constants.paddle.width, constants.paddle.height);
    ctx.fillRect(0, (state.paddles[state.sides.left] / 100 * constants.court.height) - (constants.paddle.height / 2),
                 constants.paddle.height, constants.paddle.width);
    ctx.fillRect(constants.court.width - constants.paddle.height,
                 (state.paddles[state.sides.right] / 100 * constants.court.height) - (constants.paddle.height / 2),
                 constants.paddle.height, constants.paddle.width);
    ctx.fillStyle = constants.colors.ball;
    ctx.beginPath(); 
    ctx.arc( state.ball.left, state.ball.top, constants.ball.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2 );
    ctx.fill();
  };

  var movePaddle = function (delta) {
    var newLeft = state.paddles[constants.player.id] + delta;
    if (newLeft >= 100)
      newLeft = 100;
    else if (newLeft <= 0)
      newLeft = 0;
    if (newLeft != state.paddles[constants.player.id]) {
      state.paddles[constants.player.id] = newLeft;
      socket.emit('paddle', {left: state.paddles[constants.player.id] });
      drawCanvas();
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener('keydown', function onKeyDown(aEvent) {
    switch (aEvent.which) {
      case 37: // Left
        if (state.sides.top == constants.player.id || state.sides.right == constants.player.id) movePaddle(constants.paddle.delta);
        else movePaddle(-constants.paddle.delta);
        break;
      case 39: // Right
        if (state.sides.top == constants.player.id || state.sides.right == constants.player.id) movePaddle(-constants.paddle.delta);
        else movePaddle(constants.paddle.delta);
        break;
    }
  }, false);

    </script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

***Getting error:***

**GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1423454007198-4 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the Socket.IO client-side .js file located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757728/where-is-the-socket-io-client-side-js-file-located)

Answer (score 0):

If you set up **socket.io** properly with your http server (you don't show us that part of your code), then it automatically handles the request for `"/socket.io/socket.io.js"` and serves up the `socket.io.js` file to the client that actually resides elsewhere.  In other words, it handles it all for you by intercepting the http request for `"/socket.io/socket.io.js"` and serving up the desired file from it's location in the node_modules directory that the socket.io server code came from.

Comment: i used npm install socket.io to install. how can i install with my http server?

Comment: Show us the code you use to initialize your web server and socket.io.  It is that code that makes it work.  I'm not sure, but you make also need socket.io installed locally in your project rather than globally.   Go to your project directory and then type `npm install socket.io`.

Comment: i have install socket.io in my project folder "node_modules"... i'm added my code in question, error  Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined, socket.io file not found.... thanks in advance

Comment: @Dhamu - what errors do you see in server console and client console?  I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code so you will have to troubleshoot to gather more info to lead to a clue.

Comment: error Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined, socket.io file not found....in browser console

Comment: There is something about your server-side socket.io installation that is not correct.  I don't think I can discern what that is remotely without the ability to look around at your configuration and code and perhaps even trace into the request handler on your server for `/socket.io/socket.io.js` to see why it fails.

Comment: socket.io need to install in globally or installing within the project files is enough to run??

Comment: I know it works when socket.io is installed locally IN the project directory because that's how my nodejs server works that uses it.  I don't know for sure if it works when socket.io is installed globally.  For a local installation in `projectDir` (where your local modules like app.js are), it should look like this: `projectDir/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js`.

Comment: so i can include like this now <script src="node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>... we can use like this???

Comment: No, you can't do it that way.  node.js only serves up files that it has a route for.  It is not like other web servers that serve anything in the file system.  It only serves things that there is code to serve.

Comment: wow.. its working with <script src="node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script‌​>... its working