# Fail to use socket.io not found

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

My structure

```
game.js
node_modules\
public\
       |index.html
       |js\main.js
```

`game.js` is nodejs server and in `plubic` folder is client side

In `index.html` I have

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

But when i run in web browser it say

```
GET http://localhost:1000/socket.io/socket.io.js  404
(index):3 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
    at (index):3
```

But when i download socket.io.js and make like this

```
game.js
node_modules\
public\
       |index.html
       |js\main.js
       |socket.io\socket.io.js
```

And run again it `localhost:1000` say

```
localhost:1000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lg5U91n  404 (Not Found)
```

what is mistake. I run in window. How to fix that thank.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the Socket.IO client-side .js file located?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757728/where-is-the-socket-io-client-side-js-file-located)

Comment: @AndrewBrooke sorrry but my project not working it not duplicate

Comment: socket.io.js is autogenerated and sent to the browser when requested, you dont need to download it. Please share your game.js code

Answer (score 1):

You will need to include socketio-client on the client side via the script tag. That will allow IO to be defined.

```
<script>  
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1000');
    socket.on('connect', function(data) {
        //Do Something here
    });
</script>
```

You will also need to make sure on your backed (the server that socketio is connecting to) has socketio properly defined and is being used in the HTTP server. An example would be:

```
    var express = require('express');  
    var app = express();  
    var server = require('http').createServer(app);  
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));  
    app.get('/', function(req, res,next) {  
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });

    server.listen(1000);
    io.on('connection', function(client) {  
    console.log('Client connected...');
     //socket code here
    });
```

Its very hard for us to help you without any code sample of what you are working with. The example provided is a very BASIC way of getting socketio up and running.

Checkout the socketio client github that has a quick and simple demonstration of what to do as well:
[Socket.io Client Github](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client)