# Cannot GET /socket.io/socket.io.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Why should we do this before setting the socket variable on the client side.

If I have client side script the given src file throws "Cannot GET /socket.io/socket.io.js"

Comment: It means the src path is wrong.

Comment: Sounds like an incorrectly configured server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the Socket.IO client-side .js file located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757728/where-is-the-socket-io-client-side-js-file-located)

Answer (score 0):

> Why should we do this before setting the socket variable on the client side.

Because that `<script>` tag is designed to load the client-side socket.io code which is required before you can initialize your client side socket.io connection.

> If I have client side script the given src file throws "Cannot GET /socket.io/socket.io.js"

If that URL does not work, then it means that your server is not properly configured with socket.io to serve the client-side file at that URL (which should be automatic if things are set up properly).  We can only help you solve that server configuration when we can see the relevant server code to help advise on what is wrong there.