# JavaScript server.io keeps on getting new connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, p5.js

I am very very new to javascript.

I have created a socket program using p5.js and node.js below are the required code.

**Server.js**

```
var express= require('express');
var app=express();
var server=app.listen(9800);
app.use(express.static('public'));

console.log("My server is running");
var socket=require('socket.io');

var io=socket(server);
io.sockets.on('connection',newConnection);


function newConnection(socket){
    console.log('new connection:'+socket.id);
}
```

**SKETCH.JS**

```
var socket;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(500,300);
    background(51);
    socket=io.connect('http://localhost:9800');
}

function draw() {
    noStroke();
    fill(255);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,36,36);
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FirstProject</title>
    <script src="libraries/p5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="libraries/p5.dom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.sound.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="sketch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <style> body {padding: 0; margin: 0;} canvas {vertical-align: top;} </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now the problem is even if I only open one instance of my sketch.js in the browser , the console of server.js continuously print out random ids. I have to kill it using CTRL+C . How can I correct it.

## Thanks!

Comment: show all your client side code, you're most likely creating a lot of socket.io connections.

Comment: sketch.js is my client side code.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande it is where I am connecting to socket.

Comment: That's not all your client side code, I don't see the call to `setup()` so show your full code

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I don't know who calls the setup function but I think its p5.js inbuilt function.

Comment: I only have index.html file left to show I will post it now.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande if I remove the socket=io.connect('http://localhost:9800'); from sketch.js then also it prints out new connection.

Comment: well you're probably connecting to the server from somewhere else, or your setup function is being called a lot of times. Place a console.log to check that out.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande Please notice the [tag:p5.js] tag. P5.js automatically calls various functions for you, including `setup()` and `draw()`.

Comment: @quadgen Your P5.js code looks okay to me. You're going to need to do some [debugging](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) to track down the source of the connections. Maybe add a `console.trace()` to the `setup()` function to make sure it's only being called once?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande thanks I got the bug ,there is no problem in the code, but the problem is somewhere else, refer my answer.

Comment: @KevinWorkman  thanks I got the bug ,there is no problem in the code, but the problem is somewhere else, refer my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the future readers.

If anyone of you are encountering the same problem,then you landed on the right place.
After several hours of recreation of project, web search,and online tutorials, I came to know what's wrong here.

So the problem is in the version of Socket.io on client and server.
Yes, you need to have the same version of socket.io on client as well as on the server.

The socket.io website states simply:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

So It might be confusing where is `/socket.io/socket.io.js` .Actually this file is created on fly by server code.

Refer this [Where is the Socket.IO client-side .js file located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757728/where-is-the-socket-io-client-side-js-file-located).

## Thanks!