# where is socket.io/socket.io.js location?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am making a chat app using socket.io. According to the website documentation, i have to provide a javascript file source which is:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

whereas my socket.io folder is under node_modules and on the other hand socket.io folder doesn't even contain socket.io.js, socket-client folder does. I have tried other docs but cannot find any explanation. Can anyone please explain how its working correctly even with the wrong path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the Socket.IO client-side .js file located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757728/where-is-the-socket-io-client-side-js-file-located)

Answer (score 3):

When you instantiate a `socket.io` server, it serves the client file at the `/socket.io/socket.io.js` address automatically without you having to provide anything.

You can thus choose whether you want to import the `io` from this file, or from the [socket.io-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client) module.

### Using the socket.io.js automatically provided by socket.io

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  const socket = io();
</script>
```

### Importing the io object directly with require/import and webpack/browserify

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
// or with import syntax
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io();
```

Comment: Hey MadWard, do you know the difference in why sometimes you'd have to use http:IPAddress:PORTNUMBER/socket.io/socket.io.js instead of /socket.io/socket.io.js

Comment: @m00ncake: When using socket.io, you can either use it on top of Node's HTTP server, on top of Express, or standalone. 
When using on top of Http or express, the file will be available on the same Http server, on the same port, so you don't have to specify its path. However if you're running socket.io standalone, it will boot up another http server to serve requests, and you will need to specify the path to it.
In general whenever socket.io is running on a different http instance than your main http server, you'll need to specify its path.

Comment: that's strange then, like the code I tried on ubuntu had no problem could use it as `/socket.io/socket.io.js` but in windows with the same code I had to specify it as `http://localhost:PORTNUMBER/socket.io/socket.io.js`. Do you know what might be the cause? I used it on top of http and wrapped it around express as well. It seems very weird something like this would occur. On windows, Id obtain `failed to load resource net::err_file_not_found` error. I managed to fix it by specifying the path to it with http.